# Getting Literal string error while creating Materialized View

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

Table has a column with nvarchar datatype. This column store a data in this format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.
And I need to fetch data in this format dd-mm-yyyy. So I am using this `to_char(to_date(columnname,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'),'dd-mm-yyyy')`.  I am getting correct data while fetching from select statement but when I am creating Materialized view then its throwing an error "literals string does not matching format string".

Please advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

Format mask you use is wrong; minutes are `mi`, not `mm` (that's month).

```
No : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
Yes: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss
                   --
```

---

Apart from that: saying that **query** returns desired result, are you sure that it returned all rows? GUIs (SQL Developer, TOAD, ...) usually return the first 50, 100, 500 (or whichever number it might be) rows - not all of them.

Error you got suggests that NOT ALL rows in that table contain data in format you think they have (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss).

Here's example: this is source table; note that 2nd row doesn't contain data in format you specified:

```
SQL> create table test (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, '2024-03-28 08:32:13' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '15.01.2024 13:23:32'  from dual
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID COL
---------- -------------------
         1 2024-03-28 08:32:13
         2 15.01.2024 13:23:32   --> this
```

Let's create a view:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2    select id, to_date(col, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') col
  3    from test;

View created.
```

Can I fetch from it? Nope; error just as the one you got:

```
SQL> select * From v_test;
ERROR:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string



no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

What to do? It depends on database you use. If it is 12c or newer (12.2; not sure for 12.1), apply `on conversion error` to `to_date` function. Otherwise, you'll have to *sanitize* source data and make sure that **all** rows contain values in that format. Then move on with creating the (materialized) view.

Answer (score 0):

You should find strings with date format errors.

For example:

```
-- Create test table
create table test (id, col) as
      (select 1, '2024-03-28 08:32:13' from dual union all
       select 2, '15.01.2024 13:23:32'  from dual
     );

-- Create test MV for detecting incorrect date format
create materialized view test_mv as
select id, 
to_date(col DEFAULT '9999-12-31 00:00:00' ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') col_err
from test;

-- Check incorrect ID
select * 
from test_mv
join test on test.id=test_mv.id
where test_mv.col_err = to_date('9999-12-31 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
;
```

ON CONVERSION ERROR support from 12.2